# Step by Step Setup Guide to Neo4j Mazerunner in Windows

Tags: neo4j, apache-spark, docker, neo4j-mazerunner

I would like to use the Spark-graphX packages available to Neo4j through Mazerunner, however I am an analyst and not a software person. I am running Windows 7 on my laptop and Neo4j 2.3.0, and would like a step-by-step guide explaining how I can set-up Mazerunner for both Community & Enterprise. There's a lot of mention of dockers and containers, and I have no idea what these are, or how to set them up. Simple instructions would be of sooo much help! :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question lacks of research and investment from your behalf. I'm voting to close it as too broad.

Comment: Did you see this post: http://www.lyonwj.com/2015/10/11/congressional-pagerank/ It shows how to use Mazerunner using docker compose in (mostly) a step by step format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Docker** is primarily [Operating System Level Visualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization) technology designed to run on Unix based systems **(Linux,Mac,FreeBSD)**. Luckily **Docker** provides a **Windows** version that sort of does the same thing on **Unix.**

What happens is, after you have installed **Docker**, it allows you to run what they call containers which are basically virtual machines on top of your host (**Windows 7 Running Docker**). This allows you to run services like **Neo4j** in an isolated environment. **Docker** also allows you to download and install *pre-configured, pre-compiled* images of operating systems that usually provide some sort of service or have some software *pre-installed.*

In your case, I believe all you have to do is:

1. First install [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/)
2. Use ["Docker Compose"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to download and install the images.
3. Continue [Reading the Tutorial](http://www.lyonwj.com/2015/10/11/congressional-pagerank/#importing-legis-graph) as you have now installed the required docker images

**Note:** Some of the operations, like the one in Step 2 will require command-line access and Also the creation of a "docker-compose.yml" so, be sure to visit all the links I have provided. Spend a little time going through them and you should be alright.

PS: great [blog](http://www.lyonwj.com/). definitely bookmarking it!